# Python postgreSQL is very slow

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm doing a for Loop of `x` that is a list of 30-50 URLS through 1 table to see if any of the URL matches ---  ( it took more than **5 Seconds** )

**About this system** :

- this is a free database from **Heroku.com** i'm using it as a test
- as it says on the code i'm using "**postgreSQL**
- I'm using **flask_sqlalchemy**
- i'm running this Local hosted so the front end and the backend is my laptop which is **i5 1.9ghz and 8g rams.**
- time stamp difference is around ***5 Sec*** just to check those **50 entries** with 1 user online **locally**

**python the code.**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgres://***" 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = "True" 
db = SQLAlchemy(app,session_options={"autoflush": False}) 

class test1(db.Model): 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True) 
    url = db.Column(db.String(255)) 
    code = db.Column(db.String(255)) 


    def __init__ (self,url,code): 
        self.url = url 
        self.code = code 

x = [url1,url2,url3,url4,....url50] 

t2 = datetime.time(datetime.now()) 
print("before : ",t2) 

for key in x: 

    y = test1.query.filter(test1.url == key).all() 
    if y: 
        print('----i got it') 
    else: 
        print('no') 

t3 = datetime.time(datetime.now()) 
print("after forloop : ",t3)
```

I have asked many people in the chatrooms, many of them have their own different  suspicions but no one can confirm why there is such a massive delay in a simple process.

Comment: What region is your heroku dyno located in? What region is the database located in? If one is in the EU, and the other in the US, then you have a *huge* latency issue for connections.

Comment: Also, are you sure it's even connecting to the database.  For instance have you confirmed that data is getting into the database?

Comment: You are executing 50 queries in 5 seconds. Which is 100ms per query, including  latency and overhead.

Comment: You should profile the application to see where the time is spent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters HeroKu's database is in the United States server and I'm in North Africa

Comment: @eatmeimadanish since iam getting a delayed results , that means iam connected.

Comment: @wildplasser i don't know about that it;s pretty simple List , iam not sure why does it take that much to load.

Comment: @za001a: is your **app** located in North Africa too?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes

Comment: @za001a: and are you testing this on your app, or locally and connecting to the database from your own machine?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's the same machine that runs the server and the client

Comment: @za001a: yes, but you are running flask **locally**, not on Heroku, right? But the database is on Heroku?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes , that is accurate

Comment: @za001a: then there is *very little* you can do to remedy this. Your queries have to travel a long distance to be served by a database server practically halfway across the world away from you.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating separate queries for each test, which require a new SQL statement sent to the database server.

That's not that big an issue for a local database, living on the same server. But on Heroku, the database does *not* live on the same server. The database lives somewhere else in the cloud, and it depends on your specific configuration if those two locations are near to one another, or far apart.

Connecting to **any** Heroku-hosted Postgres database from Africa is going to be slowed down by latency. That latency is compounded by the number of queries you make.

You can test how much of a latency, with a simple command:

```
time psql postgresql://*** -c select 1;
```

The difference between the *real* and *user* components is roughly the round-trip time it takes for one very simple query to reach the database server and the response to come back to you.

If you are experiencing huge delays in queries *when deployed on Heroku*, then your database instance and web Dyno are probably located in two different regions. Relocate one or the other to live in the *same* region, at the very least. If you are connecting to the database from your own machine, then you'll also see large latencies.

On the command line, run the `heroku info` command to check what region your app is located in (look for the `Region` line). Or check the *Settings* tab on the Heroku dashboard for your app. See the [Heroku *Regions* documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions) for more information, and read up on [migrating apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration) if you want to move it to another region.

If you want to move the *database* to the same region as your app, you'll have to re-create it, I believe. Create and download a full backup, drop the database add-on, re-create it, and it *should* be created in the same region as the app. Then restore the database from your backup.

Even if your app dyno and database are in the same region, you'll still see larger latencies than you'd see with Flask and Postgres installed on your local machine. How much latency you'll see also depends on the specific [Heroku Postgres plan you pick](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans). The Hobby tier (free) only allows for 20 connections and has **no** in-memory cache, so you'll need to re-use connections more often and you can't count on the server having cached table information that'd be useful for a series of related queries.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying in the loop you can query one time using in_ and search in memory.

```
test1_objs = test1.query.filter(test1.url.in_(x)).all()
test1_urls = set()
for test1_obj in test1_objs:
    test1_urls.add(test1_obj.url)
for key in x: 
    if key in test1_urls: 
        print('----i got it') 
    else: 
        print('no')
```

This will reduce the time but I think it is happening because of the network latency. If you use server on the cloud and try again the latency will be less.

Comment: that might be fine for 1 user but not for 10,000 online users